# Python - Proper syntax for 1 line if-else satement

Tags: python

To preface this, I'm very new to programming so bear with me.

I'm having issues with the syntax for a function I'm writing where I want it to check for duplicate values within a textfile that's been imported and sorted. 
I want to do this with the following code:

```
def kollaDublett(dataList):
 c = Counter(dataList)
 result = [x for x, v in c.items() if v > 1]
```

dataList is the list I'm checking for duplicates, and I'd like to somehow embedd an `if-else` to return either a True or False where `result` is defined. 
The instructor for this assignment said it was possible to do in a single line but she couldn't really make it work since she doesn't have that much experience in Python.

I can return `result` and print its value and it'll show the duplicate, but as I mentioned I would like it to check if there's a duplicate then depending on that returning either a True or False.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `return bool(result)`

Comment: Or, more explicit, `return len(result) > 0`.

Comment: @rdas That solved it, thanks a bunch!

Comment: There's a lot of text without useful information here. I had no idea what your problem was until the last paragraph. You could remove everything above that paragraph and it would be an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only a True/False list, you can use a list comprehension:

```
def kollaDublett(dataList):
    c = Counter(dataList)
    result = [True  if v > 1 else False for x, v in c.items()]
    return result
```

Instead, to return a dictionary (expression:duplicate or not):

```
 def kollaDublett(dataList):
     c = Counter(dataList)
     result = {x:(True  if v > 1 else False) for x, v in c.items()}
     return result
```

Comment: `True if some_boolean else False` is a silly way of writing `some_boolean`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, I agree. Please show a best way to obtain this result.

Comment: result = {x:(bool(v > 1)) for x, v in c.items()}